# Availability of POIs in HERE WeGo app vs Here Entrypoint (Places Search API)

Tags: rest, api, here-api

I'm looking for certain POIs using their confirmed coordinates but the Here entrypoint from Place Search API (/discover/here) doesn't provide all POIs which I could manually find in the HERE WeGo web-app.

At the beginning I thought maybe this is because the default categories are set to eat-drink, going-out and shopping? I have provided an additional parameter (cat) to my request with all the categories, but this gave me even more missing POIs.

Does anyone know why there is a such difference between the web-app and API service?

Answer (score 0):

The here-wego app doesn't use the "discover/here" endpoint so this won't show you the same results.  It uses "discover/search".

The discover/here entrypoint was designed for a different use case and its behavior is a bit odd.  It was set up for "check-ins", so it isn't guaranteed to return everything in an area.
If you want to provide your users all of the POIs in an area, you should use the browse/ endpoint.  I know that requires them to specify categories, but it's really the best choice.

Alternatively, depending on your use case, you can call discover/search the same way you called it by using the here-wego app (same query and search center).